# Does anyone recognize shortcode ig_special_heading?

Tags: shortcode

Does anyone recognize the shortcode [ig_special_heading] and can tell me what plugin or theme it comes from?

Comment: I HAVE googled and only see that a lot of sites are exposing the broken shortcode.  I'm assuming it is from a theme that a lot of people have switched away from, but that leaves no clue.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, royatl.  You should edit your question to include what you just added as a comment. That way it will be more obvious to someone reading your question that you have already done some research on it and cannot find anything on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the plugin you are looking for is https://wordpress.org/plugins/ig-shortcodes/.

Apparently it has shortcodes that start with ig_ and provides them for things like...

- Accordion
- Buttons
- Badges
- Notice box
- Columns
- Clearfix
- Divider
- Google maps
- Tabs
- Toggle